# Add character to column based on text condition using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe

I'm trying to do some data cleaning using pandas. Imagine I have a data frame which has a column call "Number" and contains data like: "1203.10", "4221","3452.11", etc. I want to add an "M" before the numbers, which have a point and a zero at the end. For this example, it would be turning the "1203.10" into "M1203.10".

I know how to obtain a data frame containing the numbers with a point and ending with zero.

Suppose the data frame is call "df".

```
pointzero = '[0-9]+[.][0-9]+[0]$'
pz = df[df.Number.str.match(pointzero)]
```

But I'm not sure on how to add the "M" at the beginning after having "pz". The only way I know is using a for loop, but I think there is a better way. Any suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
pointzero = '[0-9]+[.][0-9]+[0]$'
m = df.Number.str.match(pointzero)

df.loc[m, 'Number'] = 'M' + df.loc[m, 'Number']
```

Alternatively, using [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) and a slightly different regex:

```
pointzero = '([0-9]+[.][0-9]+[0]$)'
df['Number'] = df['Number'].str.replace(pointzero, r'M\1', regex=True))
```

Example:

```
     Number
0  M1203.10
1      4221
2   3452.11
```

Answer (score 1):

you should make dataframe or seires example for answer

example:

```
s1 = pd.Series(["1203.10", "4221","3452.11"])
s1

0    M1203.10
1        4221
2     3452.11
dtype: object
```

`str.contains` +  `boolean masking`

```
cond1 = s1.str.contains('[0-9]+[.][0-9]+[0]$')
s1.mask(cond1, 'M'+s1)
```

output:

```
0    M1203.10
1        4221
2     3452.11
dtype: object
```